# The specified message does not exist. ErrorCode:MessageNotFound Prod-WorkerError Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, queue

I have a worker role which consumes messages from an Azure Queue does some processing in the background.
When I check my log there appears to be no exception logged while processing the message but still in my logs I get the following Exception(pasting some of the relevant texts from the long error log only):

> System.Net.WebException
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException Exception messages:
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The remote
>   server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Stack Traces: at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) --- Next
>   Call Stack: at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.DeleteMessage(String
>   messageId, String popReceipt, QueueRequestOptions options,
>   OperationContext operationContext) at
>   InnovativeExams.Azure.CloudStorage.AzureQueue`1.DeleteMessage(T
>   message)  The specified message does not exist.
>   ErrorCode:MessageNotFound Prod-WorkerError Context

Here is the code I have in the worker role:

```
private void ProcessQueueMessage(object queueMessageToProcess)
        {
            var queueMessage = queueMessageToProcess as EventCompletedQueueMessage;

            try
            {
                if (_eventCompletedProcessor.Process(queueMessage))
                    _azureQueue.DeleteMessage(queueMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(string.Format("Event Completed message <{0}> was not processed due to an exception", queueMessage.Id), ex, LogSources.WorkerRole_EventCompletedDispatcher);
            }
        }
```

The above exception is caught in the above catch block and logged.

I think there is some problem when the worker role tries to Delete the message in the Queue and the message is not found.

Need help from someone to help me resolve this error and to know the background what's going wrong here.

Few Questions asked in comment:

1) Are you running multiple instances of your worker role?

A: This is an existing application and I figured out we are using *ThreadPool* to pre-instantiate, threads which stand ready to be given work.

2) How are you "getting" the messages in your worker role? Are you using some kind of leader election pattern to decide which instance gets the messages?

A: Yes there is a framework which determines the appropriate dispatcher for a QueueMessage to be processed.

3) When you get messages, what's the visibility timeout for those messages?

A: Its set to 120.

4) How long does it take for you to process these messages i.e. how much time between getting the message and deleting the messages?

A: I am not sure on this.

Comment: Few questions (Please update your question with answers to these): 1) Are you running multiple instances of your worker role? 2) How are you "getting" the messages in your worker role? Are you using some kind of leader election pattern to decide which instance gets the messages? 3) When you get messages, what's the visibility timeout for those messages? 4) How long does it take for you to process these messages i.e. how much time between getting the message and deleting the messages?

Comment: @GauravMantri Edited the Question. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain under what situation you would get the error you're encountering.

When you dequeue a message (i.e. `GET Messages` in Azure terminology), Azure Queue Service returns something called `popreceipt` which must be used to delete or update a message. This `popreceipt` is an opaque value (i.e. you should not build any business logic around it) which remains valid till the time that same message is dequeued again. When a message is dequeued again, you get a new value for `popreceipt` and you should use this new value to delete or update the message.

If you try to use an old `popreceipt` value to delete a message while the message was dequeued again (by some other process), you will get the error you're getting.

My guess is that this is what is happening in your application. Please check if this is indeed the case:

One of the worker role instances dequeues the message and starts working on that message. Based on what you told above, you hide the message for 120 seconds when you dequeue a message. I am assuming that the actual time taken for processing the message is more than 120 seconds and thus the message reappears in the queue.  There's another process which now dequeues this message (and thus you get a new `popreceipt`). However soon after the 2nd process dequeued the message, 1st process finished working on the message and now it wants to delete the message using the `popreceipt` it has. Because this popreceipt is no longer valid, any attempt to perform delete operation on that message using this popreceipt will cause a message not found error.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for explaining the in depth details on PopReceipt. I was also assuming the same situation but didn't knew in depth of this.

I wil try adding a stopwatch and then will see how much time is taken to process the messages and will update the Queue Visibility accordingly.